# How find empty input value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two checkboxes the one checkbox value is 1 and the second one is 0.
One checkbox is for enabling and other for disabling. Now I want to identify when a user clicks on Disable checkbox How I will get Disable checkbox value and if a user clicks on Enable box then how I will get Enable Checkbox value

```
<input type="radio" name="forgot_pass" class="forgot_pass_enable" value="1" checked>

<input type="radio" name="forgot_pass" class="forgot_pass_disable" value="0">
```

I have tried This code but it's not working for me any help

```
$("body").on('change', '.forgot_pass_enable', function(event) 
{
  event.preventDefault();
  /* Act on the event */  

  if($('.forgot_pass_enable').val().length > 0) 
  {
    var status = 1;

    console.log(status);
  }

  if($('.forgot_pass_disable').val().length > 0)
  {
    var status  = 0;

    console.log(statusasdad);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of the elements you've shown are checkboxes - they are radio inputs.

To get the selected value apply the same class to both elements, then hook the `change` event to that class. Then you can simply read the value from it, like this:

```js
$("body").on('change', '.forgot_pass', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var status = this.value;
  console.log(this.value === '1' ? 'enabled' : 'disabled', status);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="forgot_pass" class="forgot_pass" value="1" checked="checked">

<input type="radio" name="forgot_pass" class="forgot_pass" value="0">
```

If you did want to use a checkbox for this, which would be more applicable for an enable/disable switch, then the method is the same except you look for the `checked` property instead:

```js
$("body").on('change', '.forgot_pass', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var status = this.checked ? '1' : '0'
  console.log(status);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="forgot_pass" class="forgot_pass" value="1" checked="checked">
```